# Frontend rendering time

Tags: typo3

The frontend of my webpage, which i realized with Typo3 are rendered very slow. I install the profiler and fix one issue with the database. But my next problem is that the rendering time of the page in frontend is very slow.

After i analyze the page rendering process with profiler , i found this entry, which take the most time on page rendering.

```
HEMNU 17098175
```

I do not find any unsual part in my HMENU, have someone the same issue?

**Here is my HEMNU**

```
lib.mainNavi = HMENU
lib.mainNavi {

    special = directory
    special.value = {$const.navigation.main.entryId}

    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        wrap = <ul class="nav navbar-nav">|</ul>
        expAll = 1
        entryLevel = 0
        NO = 1
        NO {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="first">|</li>|*|<li>|</li>|*|<li class="last">|</li>
        }

        CUR = 1
        CUR {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="first current">|</li>|*|<li class="current">|</li>|*|<li class="last current">|</li>
        }

        ACT = 1
        ACT {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="first active">|</li>|*|<li class="current">|</li>|*|<li class="last current">|</li>
        }


        IFSUB {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="first dropdown">|</li>|*|<li class="dropdown">|</li>|*|<li class="last dropdown">|</li>
        }

    }

    2 = TMENU
    2 {
        wrap = <ul class="oa-dropdown-menu">|</ul>
        expAll = 1

        NO = 1
        NO {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="li-level2">|</li>
            ATagParams = class="level-2"
        }

        CUR < .NO
    }

    3 = TMENU
    3 {
        wrap = <ul class="oa-dropdown-menu-3">|</ul>
        NO = 1
        NO {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="li-level3">|</li>
            ATagParams = class="level-3"
        }

        CUR < .NO
    }
}


lib.submenu = HMENU
lib.submenu {

    special = directory

    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        wrap = <ul class="mobileSecondLevel">|</ul>
        expAll = 1
        entryLevel = 1
        NO = 1
        NO {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="first">|</li>|*|<li>|</li>|*|<li class="last">|</li>
        }

        CUR = 1
        CUR {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="first current">|</li>|*|<li class="current">|</li>|*|<li class="last current">|</li>
        }

        ACT = 1
        ACT {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="first active">|</li>|*|<li class="actve">|</li>|*|<li class="last active">|</li>
        }
    }

    2 = TMENU
    2 {
        wrap = <ul class="mobileThirdLevel">|</ul>
        entryLevel = 2
        NO = 1
        NO {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="first">|</li>|*|<li>|</li>|*|<li class="last">|</li>
        }

        CUR = 1
        CUR {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="first current">|</li>|*|<li class="current">|</li>|*|<li class="last current">|</li>
        }

        ACT = 1
        ACT {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="first active">|</li>|*|<li class="actve">|</li>|*|<li class="last active">|</li>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Apparently you have some problems with DB database your HMENU is quite normal and it should render quite fast (if have less than several thousands pages in the menu ;)) check the answer for your prev question -   with my tips about DB performance

Comment: @biesior many thanks for your support, i will try the database changes, on success or not success i will give a feedback

Comment: @biesior in this table tx_extensionmanager_domain_model_extension i have 35160 entries, should i truncate the entries? On clean up in install tool this table also listed with the cache tables.

Comment: It's a list of extensions that you can install, you can empty it, Extension Manager will retrieve next time from server, anyway it does not affect FE rendering times in any case